# SQLのWhere句の書き方、AND・ORの評価順

Tags: php, mysql, sql

下記の条件に当てはまるようにsqlを書いたのですが、うまくいきません。どこが間違っているでしょうか？
・created(DATETIME型)が2016-02または、2016-01(2016-01というところには$_GETの変数を埋め込んでいます。)
・billの値が0であるか、またはmodified(datetime型）から15日以上経過している。

```
select id
from contents
where
    DATE_FORMAT(created,'y-m') = 2016-02 OR
    DATE_FORMAT(created,'y-m') = adddate(2016-02, interval -1 month) AND
    bill = 0 OR
    now() > (`modified` + INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Comment: 本質からは逸れますが、"$_GETの変数を埋め込んでいます"の部分は必ずSQLインジェクション対策を行ってください。

Answer (score 1):

[演算子の優先順位の問題](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/21689/5793)の他にも、DATE_FORMATの書式指定が間違っています。`DATE_FORMAT(created,'y-m')`は`y-m`という文字列を出力しています。意図しているのは`DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m')`ではないでしょうか。

また、`2016-02`と言う文字列ですが、sprintfや文字列連結でSQLを生成している場合、文字列リテラルになっていません。数値の式と解釈されるので、`2014`になります(その場合セキュリティ上の問題も考えられます)。パラメータの埋め込みにプレースホルダを使用しているのであれば問題ありません。

他にも質問に書かれている意図を反映していない点があるかもしれませんがすべては確認していません。

意図通りに動かない時は、いきなり複雑な事をやらずに、CLIなどで関数の出力や条件を分解するなどして少しずつ動きを確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

ANDのほうがORより優先順位が高いので、ORの結果(2か所)を括弧でくくる必要があります。

```
select id
  from contents
 where 
     -- 括弧でくくる
     (DATE_FORMAT(created,'y-m') = 2016-02 OR DATE_FORMAT(created,'y-m') = adddate(2016-02, interval -1 month))
   AND
     -- 括弧でくくる
     (bill=0 OR now() > (`modified` + INTERVAL 15 DAY))
```

Comment: 思っているように取得ができないようです。。
どのような原因が考えられますでしょうか。

Comment: @rei0328 `DATE_FORMAT`の結果は文字列なので、それと`DATE`を比較すると意図しない結果になる可能性があります。一度条件に含まれる値をSELECTして想定通りになってるか確認したほうが良いのでは。